# Need to display javascript value in anchor tag of jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to pass the `userid` variable through anchor tag .. Here I attached code for that.

Code :

```
<td colspan="2" align="right"><div align="center">User Id</div></td>
<td><input class="textbox" type="text" id="userid" ><a href="access.jsp?userid='+userid'" 
"></a></td></tr>
```

Javascript :

```
 var  userid ="MK";// this value is getting fetched correctly using document.getElementByName
```

Just I need to display in anchor tag.How can I do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You're question is very unclear. Can you share more of your code? Including the HTML. And perhaps expand on your problem and what you want. Please also look at how to mark up your post for properly displaying code snippets. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to be more clear with your Question.
You should show all related parts of your code so people can figure out what exactly you need.
Also Stackoverflow provides some markup so you can insert blocks of code - very useful, I recommend looking it up :)

#### Assuming you already have the anchor `<a>` tag

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="anchor"></a>
```

JS

```
// your code (fetching data) ...
document.getElementById('anchor').setAttribute('href', 'google.com?userid=" + userid)
```

Comment: <h2>JavaScript Variables</h2>

<p>Strings are written with quotes.</p>
<p>Numbers are written without quotes.</p>



<script>

var kxi="kroger";

</script>

<body>
<a href="http://google.com?userid="+kxi> Link</a>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Here is an demo example .. want to pass this kxi js variable in anchor tag..

Hope this is clear now!

Comment: Again, I'd recommend you adding this to your original post (there is an **edit** button right below it).

Comment: You are actually looking for a way **not to display** this in the anchor tag, but rather set it as part of the **anchor tags attribute href**. Let me adjust my code example.